# Differences between character() and "" in R

Tags: r, character, string

Just realize the output is different:

```
> y=""
> y
[1] ""
> y=character()
> y
character(0)
```

However, nothing odd has happened. And I am not clear about these differences, and want to keep this problem(if any) clear in mind. So, thank you for helping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing the length (number of elements) of a vector with the number of characters in a string:

Consider these three things:

```
> x=c("","")
> y=""
> z=character()
```

Their length is the number of elements in the vector:

```
> length(x)
[1] 2
> length(y)
[1] 1
> length(z)
[1] 0
```

To get the number of characters, use `nchar`:

```
> nchar(x)
[1] 0 0
> nchar(y)
[1] 0
> nchar(z)
integer(0)
```

Note that `nchar(x)` shows how many letters in each element of `x`, so it returns an integer vector of two zeroes. `nchar(y)` is then an integer vector of one zero.

So the last one, `nchar(z)` returns an `integer(0)`, which is an integer vector of no zeroes. It has length of zero. It has no elements, but if it did have elements, they would be integers.

`character(0)` is an empty vector of character-type objects. Compare:

```
> character(0)
character(0)
> character(1)
[1] ""
> character(2)
[1] "" ""
> character(12)
[1] "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
```

Answer (score 6):

`character(0)` is vector of character type with ZERO elements. But `""` is character type vector with one element, which is equal to empty string.

Answer (score 3):

If `y=""`, then `length(y)` is `1`. 
On the other hand, if `y=character()`, then `length(y)` is `0`