# How do you skip empty vectors in R

Tags: r

I have a vector x with nothing in it.

```
dput(x)
""
```

When I do, `length(x)` or `nrow(data.frame(x))`, it comes out as 1.

How would I set up a if statement where if it is empty, go to the next?

I have it as:

```
if(length(x)>1){
```

does not seem to be working.

Comment: The `>1` seems both wrong and unnecessary: wrong because it will deliver the wrong result if length=1 and unnecessary since if length==0 then the `>` is not needed since if will be `FALSE` when coerced to logical. If you really want the number of characters then use `nchar`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differences between character() and "" in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040895/differences-between-character-and-in-r)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your vector is not empty, it consist of 1 empty string (a string of zero length).

```
x <- ""
dput(x)
## ""
```

Here, you want to test if `nchar(x) == 0` or `all(nchar(x) == 0)`. Alternatively, you may wish to check if `nzchar(x)` returns `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `x` is not "empty". It's a vector of length 1, and the single entry is the empty character string. This is different from `NULL` or `NA` or many other ways of defining "emptiness" in R. (Rather Zen.)

The answer will depend on what else could conceivably be in `x`. @gagolews already gave a nice answer. Alternatives could include `all(x=="")` or similar. Regardless of what you do, think about whether `x` could contain `NULL`, or `NA` with or without bona fide strings mixed in.

I think you would find [*The R Inferno*](http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/) most enlightening.